# Uploadify always encounter error 'test.jpg (79.37KB) - HTTP Error'

Tags: jquery, file-upload, struts2, uploadify

I'm using Uploadify (and with Struts2 as back-end side) to upload file, whenever after I selected a file, a `IO Error` or `HTTP Error` would happen:

```
test.jpg (79.37KB) - HTTP Error
```

Here is JavaScript code:

```
$(select).uploadify({
            'uploader' : BASE_PATH + 'js/uploadify-v2.1.4/uploadify.swf',
            'script' : 'attachement/doUploadImage.action?jsessionid='+sessionId,
            'scriptData': {'folder': 'customer'},
            'auto' : true,
            'buttonText': 'Select a image',
            'displayData': 'percentage',
            'fileDesc': 'Support Formats:jpg/gif/jpeg/png/bmp.',
            'fileExt': '*.jpg;*.gif;*.jpeg;*.png;*.bmp',
            'multi': false,
            'cancelImg' : BASE_PATH + 'js/uploadify-v2.1.4/cancel.png',
            'fileDataName': 'uploadFile',
            'onComplete' : function(event, queueID, fileObj, response, data) {
               // Do something
            },
            'onError': function(error) {
            }
        });
```

And following is the struts.xml configuation:

```
<package name="attachement" namespace="/attachement" extends="test-default">
        <action name="do*" method="{1}" class="com.test.AttachmentAction">
        </action>
    </package>
```

And below is code in AttachmentAction:

```
private String folder;

private File uploadFile;

public void doUploadImage() {
    Upload result = new Upload();

    try {
        log.info("Begin uploading the file " + uploadFile);

        String filePath = IoUtil.saveAttachment(uploadFile, folder);

        result.setSuccess(true);
        result.setFilePath(filePath);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        result.setSuccess(false);
        result.setMessage("Error: " + e.getMessage());
    }

    this.outJson(result);
}
```

And following is the information under firebug:
[image]

I don't know what makes this error happen? Can anybody gives me help. Thanks so much.

Comment: Use fiddler to get more information on the error, including the status code. That would be helpful in determining the issue. http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/

Comment: did you put java.io.tempdir system property?

Comment: Hi @Roman C, I have not set java.io.tempdir property, how do I set this?

Comment: java -Djava.io.tmpdir=PATH?

Comment: you also need setter for upload file

Comment: I don't think these system settings cause this problem.

Comment: What do you think what cause this problem?

Comment: Something like security, action URL, etc. Because I have studied some cases of uploadify, none of them has said that system properties should be set.

Comment: Could you post the stacktrace?

Comment: By debugging upload request, I found that request don't go to the server side. I think the 'script' property is ok.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few days later, this problem is solved. The root cause is that my project didn't include the Apache Jars upon which struts 2 upload functionality depends.

```
commons-fileupload.jar
commons-io.jar
```

Thanks!